# Windows authentication enabled web site stuck in IPad when i cancel NTLM prompt

Tags: ipad, ios6, safari, active-directory, windows-authentication

i have windows authentication enabled website for my internal users, when i open my website into IPAD(safari browser), windows authentication box appears.
when i put credential and press Login Button, it works fine. but when i press cancel button from windows authentication box. it does not redirect 401 page, it stacks, nothing happens

it happens only safari browser on Ipad
anyone can help me ?

Comment: Could anyone help me, i need urgent response.